# Should I import components like buttons in my react project

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a react app, and it's the first time I've done a really big project. I've just heard someone in a video briefly mention that large companies like facebook have a few button designs, which I guess they then import into there project. Is this so the buttons across the app have consistent designs, colors, etc. If so, will this be better or worse for performance if I just make 2-3 button designs and then import them into other components when I need them. I've currently got about 100 buttons in my app, which all look fairly similar, but aren't completely the same, mostly just the padding and height are different, but I've given every button a unique className and then redone the css for every button. This seems like it would be bad for performance and also the overall design of the app.

This is how I've made the new button component, would this be correct and should I even make button components for my app?

```
import React from 'react'

const Button1 = ({ text, width, height }) => {
    return (
        <button className='main-btn1' style={{ width, height }}>
            {text}
        </button>
    )
}

export default Button1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the projects I've worked on export have some basic components, including Buttons, Modals, etc. Then just import the stuff where you need them. If you have 100 different buttons, with only minor changes, I'd just make a few components like `PrimaryButton`, `SecondaryButton`, etc. If you need more flexible styling, pass the extra styles as props and use a default value for the default styles. It's a better practice as you can avoid writing practically the same code 100 different times. Plus, it's probably better than loading all the extra CSS code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to start using button components, is the way I've created the button correct? or should I be doing it a better way than that?

Comment: @willmahon Ditch the classes. If you're using a different class for every button, it's the same as the other way. If it was me, I'd use a `btn` class for the base styles, and for the stuff I want to change, I'll use inline styles in js.

Comment: How do you resize the button for different screen sizes though if I don't give the button a className?

Comment: I usually use styled-components, so I can give media queries through that. If that's not available, try giving the padding in `em` or `rem` instead of pixels so it changes with the font size. Or if all your button sizes change with the screen size, just change the properties of the common button class.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into styled components